# Cannot export image on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, image

I try to get a satelital image on my google drive by using the code:

The image variable is mejorImagen, the problem is this:

[image]

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: mejorImagen,
  description: mejorImagen.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd').getInfo(),
  scale: 10,
  region: Cuadro
});
```

Cannot export image on Google Earth engine.

Code:

```
var Cuadro = 
    /* color: #0b4a8b */
    /* shown: false */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "marker"
      },
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry({
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "geometries": [
        {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -71.6914011142377,
            -16.572221685382196
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                -71.80297441812573,
                -16.271598607085643
              ],
              [
                -71.80297441812573,
                -16.58838812641333
              ],
              [
                -71.32232256265698,
                -16.58838812641333
              ],
              [
                -71.32232256265698,
                -16.271598607085643
              ]
            ]
          ],
          "geodesic": false,
          "evenOdd": true
        }
      ],
      "coordinates": []
    });
var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
//var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
//var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1')
.filterBounds(Cuadro)
.filterDate('2020-03-20','2020-03-24')
//La propiedad es diferente para Landsat 8 y Sentinel 2A
//sort('CLOUD_COVER');
//Esto ordena de menor a mayor, propiedad de Sentinel 2A
.sort('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT');

var conteo = image.size();
print('conteo de imágenes', conteo);

var mejorImagen = ee.Image(image.first());

var mejorImagen = mejorImagen.clip(Cuadro);

print('La primera con menos nubosidad', mejorImagen);
//Convertir la lista de imagenes en una lista
var listaImagenes = image.toList(image.size());

var segundaMejorImagen = ee.Image(listaImagenes.get(1));
var terceraMejorImagen = ee.Image(listaImagenes.get(2));

print('mejorImagen', mejorImagen.get('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT'));
print('segundaMejorImagen', segundaMejorImagen.get('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT'));
print('terceraMejorImagen', terceraMejorImagen.get('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT'));
//Verdadero color para Landsat 8 y Sentinel 2A es 4 3 2
//True color para Landsat 5 y 7 es 3 2 1
Map.addLayer(mejorImagen, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 3000}, 'image');
var fechaAdquirida = mejorImagen.get('DATE_ACQUIRED');
print('Fecha adquirida', fechaAdquirida);
//Para sentinel 2A las bandas de 10 m son 2,3,4,8
//Para Landsat 8 las bandas de 30 m son 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
//Para landsat 5 y 7 las bandas de 30 m son 1,2,3,4,5,7
//mejorImagen = mejorImagen.select(['B2','B3','B4','B8'])
mejorImagen = mejorImagen.select(['B2','B3','B4','B8']);


//Map.centerObject(mejorImagen,10);

//Export.image.toDrive({
  //  El clip define el área de interés real
    //image: mejorImagen,
    //description: 'Sentinel2A_Op_2018',
    //scale: 10,
    //region: operaciones
    //});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: mejorImagen,
  description: mejorImagen.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd').getInfo(),
  scale: 10,
  region: Cuadro
});
```

---

Error:

[image: error]

> Error: GeometryConstructors.MultiGeometry: Geometry coordinate
>   projection requires non-zero maxError

Comment: Please expand on the problem you are having: what error message do you get, what do think is causing the problem, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue arises because you were trying to export the image clipped on a GeometryCollection instead of Polygon. Try this:

```
var CuadroPoly = Cuadro.geometries(); // Create a new polygon to clip the image to
CuadroPoly = CuadroPoly.get(1);
var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterBounds(Cuadro)
  .filterDate('2020-03-20','2020-03-24')
  .sort('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT');

var conteo = image.size();
print('conteo de imágenes', conteo);

var mejorImagen = ee.Image(image.first());

var mejorImagen = mejorImagen.clip(CuadroPoly);

print('La primera con menos nubosidad', mejorImagen);
//Convertir la lista de imagenes en una lista
var listaImagenes = image.toList(image.size());

var segundaMejorImagen = ee.Image(listaImagenes.get(1));
var terceraMejorImagen = ee.Image(listaImagenes.get(2));

print('mejorImagen', mejorImagen.get('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT'));
print('segundaMejorImagen', segundaMejorImagen.get('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT'));
print('terceraMejorImagen', terceraMejorImagen.get('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT'));
//Verdadero color para Landsat 8 y Sentinel 2A es 4 3 2
//True color para Landsat 5 y 7 es 3 2 1
Map.addLayer(mejorImagen, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 3000}, 'image');
var fechaAdquirida = mejorImagen.get('DATE_ACQUIRED');
print('Fecha adquirida', fechaAdquirida);
//Para sentinel 2A las bandas de 10 m son 2,3,4,8
//Para Landsat 8 las bandas de 30 m son 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
//Para landsat 5 y 7 las bandas de 30 m son 1,2,3,4,5,7
//mejorImagen = mejorImagen.select(['B2','B3','B4','B8'])
mejorImagen = mejorImagen.select(['B2','B3','B4','B8']);

var date = ee.Date(mejorImagen.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
date = date.getInfo();

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: mejorImagen,
  description: date,
  scale: 10,
  region: CuadroPoly,
  maxPixels: 130000000000
});
```

Comment: The export worked for me after 6 minutes of processing time.

Comment: That is right, it worked. Tks

Comment: Glad it helped. If you wouldn't mind, please accept it as the correct answer :)